# Вывод часов - assembler

Tags: ассемблер, port

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Есть такая программа, которая выводит системное время. Как сделать, чтобы время менялось, проще говоря вывести часы. Читала, что необходимо использовать регистр состояния OAh.

```
org 100h

    mov dh,10
    mov dl,35
    mov bh,0
    mov ah,2
    int 10h

    push 04h
    call rejestr
    add sp,2

    push ax
    call bcd
    add sp,2

    push ':'
    call znak
    add sp,2

    push 02h
    call rejestr
    add sp,2

    push ax
    call bcd
    add sp,2

    push ':'
    call znak
    add sp,2

    push 00h
    call rejestr
    add sp,2

    push ax
    call bcd
    add sp,2

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h

rejestr:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    add bp,4
    mov ax,0
    mov al,[bp]
    out 70h,al
    in al,71h
    pop bp
    ret

znak:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    add bp,4
    push dx
    mov dl,[bp]
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
    pop dx
    pop bp
    ret

bcd:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    add bp,4
    push ax
    mov dl,al
    shr dl,4
    add dl,'0'
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    pop ax
    mov dl,al
    and dl,0fh
    add dl,'0'
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    pop bp
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы время менялось нужно его менять :)

Например, повесить обработчик `int 1Ch`, в нём проверять не случилась ли смена секунды. Если да, то выводить новое значение времени. А можно вообще не проверять смену секунды, а просто выводить новое время каждый 18-й по счёту вызов. Тут возможна потеря точности (будет "уплывать" примерно по 0.2 секудны), но решение о допустимости такого подхода принимать вам.

При этом советую отказаться от использования функций `int 21h` для вывода, а использовать функции BIOS (`int 10h`). Дело в нереентеребельности функций DOS: если прерывание от таймера пришло в тот момент, когда какая-либо функция DOS выполняется, вы не можете вызывать свои функциии `int 21h` (на самом деле тут есть варианты, но в вашем случае проще не связываться).

Или да, читать системный таймер самостоятельно в цикле, и при смене секунд выводить новое время.  А читать системный таймер можно разными способами. Всякие варианты описаны, например, [по этой ссылке](http://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp.old/v33/ch5.htm).

Только вариант с обработчиком прерывания таймера - лучше :)

Comment: не подскажете, как это сделать?
"а просто выводить новое время каждый 18-й по счёту вызов"

Comment: @YanaGlance, заведите переменную, изначально там 0. При каждом срабатывании таймера (вызове вашего обработчика `int 1Ch`) увеличивайте её значение на 1. Получили 18 - обнулили и вывели время.

Comment: А в чём смысл выводить каждый 18й, если время всё равно надо получать для вывода?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а какой смысл делать ненужную работу, если время обновлять нужно только раз в секунду (если, конечно, бОльшая точность по условию не нужна)? Итого, 17 вызовов обработчик прерывания увеличивает и проверяет счётчик, а как он дойдёт до 18 - тогда уже и время получать, и выводить его.